# Can I redefine a superclass's property in a subclass? (c#'s new modifier maybe?)

Tags: dart

Kennel has a Dog.

KennelWithPlayground (of type Kennel) has a DogWithABall (of type Dog) and cannot have just a normal Dog.

I want to be able to treat any type of Kennel like it has a normal Dog.

So, I would like to redefine a property of a super class, in a subclass.  The new property will be a subclass of the property's superclass.  Is this possible in Dart?  (something like the 'new' modifier in c# maybe). Or is there another way to achieve this?

The following code does not work because in the KennelWithPlayground class, DogWithABall is not a valid override of Dog.

```
class Dog {
  String get bark => "woof";
}

class DogWithBall extends Dog {
  String get ballAction => "boing";
}

abstract class Kennel {
  Dog dog;
}

class KennelWithPlayground implements Kennel {
  DogWithBall dog; //**invalid override**
  KennelWithPlayground(DogWithBall dog);
}

void processKennel(Kennel kennel){
  kennel.dog.bark;

  if (kennel is KennelWithPlayground)
    print(kennel.dog.ballAction);
  else
    print("Bored dog");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions that I can think of off the top of my head.  You can use the `covariant` keyword to allow the override, at the expense of a runtime check, or you can use generics to track the types statically.  For the former approach, you would change the definition of `Kennel` as follows:

```dart
    abstract class Kennel {
      covariant Dog dog;
    }
```

Or alternatively, change the definition of `KennelWithPlayGround`:

```dart
    class KennelWithPlayground implements Kennel {
      covariant DogWithBall dog;
      KennelWithPlayground(DogWithBall dog);
    }
```

This will allow the override, but will cause a runtime check to happen on every write to the `dog` field to make sure that whatever is being written is actually a `DogWithBall`.

An alternative is to use generics as follows:

```dart
    class Dog {
      String get bark => "woof";
    }

    class DogWithBall extends Dog {
      String get ballAction => "boing";
    }

    abstract class Kennel<DogKind extends Dog> {
      DogKind dog;
    }

    class KennelWithPlayground implements Kennel<DogWithBall> {
      DogWithBall dog;
      KennelWithPlayground(DogWithBall dog);
    }

    void processKennel(Kennel kennel){
      kennel.dog.bark;

      if (kennel is KennelWithPlayground)
        print(kennel.dog.ballAction);
      else
        print("Bored dog");
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks @LeafPeterson, all these options work and work well

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but if and only if the property has no setter.

```dart
class Foo {
  final num value;
  Foo(this.value);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  final double value;
  Bar(this.value);
}
```